# How to add header-only dependency using gradle in C++

Tags: c++, gradle

I have created a c++ multiproject using gradle. I have a subproject which  only includes c++ template classes. Now I want to use these template classes as a dependency for another of my subprojects.

Already tried defining the header-only project by using 'cpp-library' plugin and using an implementation dependency through gradle, but as I already know because the header files are actually template classes there is no binary generated. So no luck with that.
I also checked the example in https://github.com/gradle/native-samples/tree/37abb6a6a51bb2075fcc9ffbf15a3d396a3fbd88/cpp/header-only-library
but there they are only defining a self contained project that runs unit tests without any other project relying on it. (if I am not mistaken)

So the main function that wants to use the template class starts as following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "MyStack.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    try {
        MyStack<int> myList;
```

where MyStack is the template class that exists in another subproject and the build.gradle.kts file is as follows:

```
plugins {
    `cpp-application`
}

application {
    targetMachines.add(machines.linux.x86_64)

    dependencies {
        implementation(project(":MyStack"))
    }
}
```

The header-only project has the following build.gradle.kts file:

```
    `cpp-library`
}

library {
    targetMachines.add(machines.linux.x86_64)
    linkage.set(listOf(Linkage.STATIC))
}
```

Which as said above will not work because the source files are template files and cannot be compiled and linked.

Is there any option by using gradle to overcome this situation?

Comment: Header only library - is a compile time units for C++. So, if you'd like to re-use this library for your C++ sub-projects - simply add location of your compile time library header files as additional include directory/ies for another sub-projects. If you don't want to re-compile those headers for each depending sub-projects, think about converting your compile time library to static or dynamic library.

Comment: Just note that my header only library actually includes template classes so it cannot be converted to static or dynamic library because it cannot be compiled. Additionally I was thinking that somehow I should be able to reuse this part of the code without copying it to different locations depending the project that wants to use the library.

Comment: Practically possible, if you limit used types. I.e. something like: `typedef LinkedList<jstring> java_string_list_t;  java_string_list_t new_java_strnigs(std::vector<std::string>&& strings) { .... }`

Comment: I do not want to limit the used types.